# How can I case-insensitive sort a 2D List in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, case-insensitive

I have a 2D List like this:

```
mylist = [[1, "Banana", "description"],[2, "Peach", "description"],[1,"apple", "description"],[2, "orange", "description"]]
```

I want to sort the list first by the numbers and then by the "name" of the object. But when I sort it with `sorted(mylist)` I get following output:

```
mylist=[[1, 'Banana', 'description'], [1, 'apple', 'description'], [2, 'Peach', 'description'], [2, 'orange', 'description']]
```

Instead, I want a case insensitive sort by the name:

```
mylist = [[1, 'apple', 'description'], [1, 'Banana', 'description'], [2, 'orange', 'description'], [2, 'Peach', 'description']]
```

I tried the key `key=str.casefold` but that doesn't work, as I get following error message:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'casefold' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object
```

Comment: If you make those actually strings, then people can give executable examples. And please don't call variables `list` as it shadows the `list()` function. If you really don't have a better name, call it `list_`

Comment: @MartinThoma. Excellent advice. I think `mylist` is the most common version I see for toy examples.

Comment: The syntax of your examples is wrong so you clearly haven’t executed these - always try examples yourself before putting ‘code’ into a question

Comment: You really should fix up your question. It's a good question, but will likely keep getting downvoted if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items being passed to the key are `list`s. At the same time, a key can output a sequence such as a `tuple` or a `list`, which as you can already see, will be compared lexicographically. That's what is happening when you don't specify a key explicitly.

So a key can transform an input list and return another list:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda row: [row[0], row[1].casefold()])
```

It is up to you whether you want to do anything with the third element of each row in the key.